# How do I prevent JDeveloper from running the Integrated WebLogic Server instead of my Java file?

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

I've been using JDeveloper for quite some time now with no problems until yesterday. Now instead of running the Java file I've set in the run configuration like it has hundreds of times before, it tries to get me to create a default domain so it can run something called an Integrated WebLogic Server. I'm entireley self-taught on JDeveloper and I don't know what most of the settings mean. How do I change the toolbar button back to running the file instead of this WebLogic Server thing?

I started the program and tried to run the Java file I'd set in the run configuration using the run button on the toolbar. It opened a window asking me to create a default domain. I thought something had been updated and just went along with it. Then, whenever I clicked the toolbar run button it started something called IntegratedWebLogicServer instead of running the file. The only way to run the file was to right-click and select run from the popup menu. I checked for updates and updated everything. Now it's back to asking me to create a domain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tell us your exact JDev version, please!

Can you show ua an image of your run configuration?